# JSON translation system

Tags: java, json, jackson, translation

I'm making a little game using Java, a project of mine. As an experiment, I'm attempting to add language support so that the two people that play my game can switch the language of the game's text freely.

Using JSON, I created a file which contains some text which I plan on translating to other languages. It's stored in EN_US.json:

```
{
    "name": "English",
    "country": "US",
    "code": "EN_US",
    "index": 0,
    "translations": {
        "mainMenu": {
            "gameName": "Ludicrous Swole",
            "startConfirm": "PRESS ANY KEY TO BEGIN",
            "singlePlayer": "Singleplayer",
            "multiPlayer": "Multiplayer",
            "quit": "Quit",
            "options": {
                "desc": "Options"
            },

            "easy": "Easy",
            "normal": "Normal",
            "hard": "Hard"
        }
    }
}
```

Using the JSON interpretation library Jackson (or any other, for that matter), how can I convert this into something I can easily reference in strings?

```
System.out.println("The difficulty is set to " + /* translations.mainMenu.easy */);
```

It would also be helpful if answers could provide relevant imports because I'm not good at that.

Comment: You can try using GSON library. http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html

Answer (score -1):

Google's GSON maybe better .

You can read this file line by line assemble them a single line
and transfer to another point